# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flexslider is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Hi I am new to this but from few days my wordpress site is giving this error instead of loading flexslider. it's stuck at loading slider.. and its giving this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).flexslider is not a function
at jquery.flexslider-min.js?ver=4.6.2:41
at dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
at r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
```

my site is womennow.in

and error at

```
    (function($){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade", controlNav: "thumbnails", directionNav: false,
        start: function(slider){
          jQuery('.slider-container').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
     jQuery('.sliderTitle').css('opacity',0.9);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need to include the flexslider library in your page. It's not a standard part of jQuery

Comment: Have you verified that jquery is not linked as a reference more than once?

Comment: Yes it is not referenced more than once.

Comment: Not sure, but you could try: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ load() method as shortcut for: .on( "load", handler ) is removed from newer versions of jQuery. Try with $(window).on('load'...)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not reference inside the function either try change to jQuery the injection in your function or change to `$` your call inside the function, make sure that you're importing the library:

```
 (function(jQuery){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade", controlNav: "thumbnails", directionNav: false,
        start: function(slider){
          jQuery('.slider-container').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
     jQuery('.sliderTitle').css('opacity',0.9);
    });
}(jQuery));
```